# Insert apenas se data não estiver duplicada - Python

Tags: mysql, python

Boa tarde Pessoal!
Hoje estou fazendo um insert que não confere se tal registro já foi inserido no banco de dados. Através das variáveis: nome, data e numero é realizado um insert na tabela faltantes:

```
nome = message.who_name
numero = message.who
data = date.today()

sql = "insert into faltantes values ('', %s, %s, %s)
valores = (nome, numero, data)
cursor.execute(sql, valores)
```

Gostaria de saber se podem me ajudar, de forma que esse insert só seja realizado se o nome do aluno já não estiver inserido e a data não conter a data do dia.
Essa data do dia me refiro a função date.today

Agradeço desde já quem puder me ajudar!

Comment: Conhece a cláusula `unique` do SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma chave única:

```
CREATE TABLE faltantes (
   UNIQUE KEY(nome,data) 
);
```

Comment: Obrigado Marcos Grzeça, utilizei seu comentário + insert ignore e consegui cadastrar e não está + duplicando.